# How to draw lines without deleting the old ones every time?

Tags: android, arraylist, line, ondraw, ontouch

I'm working on a code, which should make lines. You can touch the screen on two diffrent places, the program gets the x/y values and draws a line. So that's working fine!
I want the program now to save the lines. So you can touch the screen multiple times and the program makes a line from the first to the second touch, from the third to the fourth and so on, and displays them all. 
I tried to do this with an arraylist, but it still didn't worked. 
Here is the code, which draws the lines, but doesn't sve them.

**So the code works now! I made it with Paths and it's working fine!
Thank for your help!**

```
package com.example.linienmachen;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class Touchclass extends View {
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();
int count = 1;

public Touchclass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

if ((count%2 != 0)){
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);}
}

 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
float eventX = event.getX();
float eventY = event.getY();

switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

    count++;

    if(count%2 != 1){
    path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
  return true;
    }
    if(count%2 != 0){
    path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
    break;
    }
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

  break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
  // nothing to do
  break;
default:
  return false;
}

// Schedules a repaint.
invalidate();
return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways to do this.

1)Store the location of each line, and redraw each line in every onDraw call.

2)Use a bitmap.  Every time a new line is created, draw the line directly to the bitmap.  Then your onDraw function just draws this bitmap to the screen.

Method 2 uses more memory but has better performance.  Method 1 doesn't scale to hundreds of lines, but it takes a lot less memory.

Comment: Thx for the answer! To 1) How can i store the lines?

Comment: Store both endpoints.  So you'd have an inner class Line with 4 values (xstart, ystart, xend, yend) and have an ArrayList of those structures.  In onDraw you'll iterate through the list and draw each line.

Comment: So I'm here again, I stored the points, but I have problems with the iteration, can you give me the specific code I need for this program?
In my program the lines are made from every point to each other point...

Comment: You could also use a `Path`. I'm guessing this is cheaper in memory, and it is way faster than iterating through a list of lines.

Comment: @Niek Haarman, I don't know how to use Path, do you have an example or can you explane it to me?

Comment: Use Path.moveTo and Path.lineTo. You can do this multiple times in a single path. At last do canvas . drawPath.

Comment: Ok, I will try it tomorrow and I will show you the result, hope you will see it then. Thank you btw!